# Unable to passthrough primary gpu in triple gpu setup. Ubuntu hangs on boot

Tags: boot, gpu

I have recently built a system with 3 GPU's. Im trying to passthrough two gpu's to use them in vm's and use the third as host GPU. I have succsessfully been able to passthrough the second slot GPU fully working in a Windows 10 vm. All GPU's are working and displaying picture on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install. My problem occurs when trying to passthrough the primary GPU in the first PCI-E slot. When doing so Ubuntu freezes/fails to boot right before the graphics driver is supposed to load.

I have tried the following:
Blacklisted gpu drivers,
Disabling the Framebuffer

Other notes:
My IOMMU groups are properly separated,
Mainboard seems unable to set primary GPU in Bios

System specs:

- CPU: Ryzen 9 3900x
- Mainboard: Asus Prime x570 Pro
- GPU1: Nvidia GTX 970 (PCI-E 1)
- GPU2: Nvidia GTX 780 (PCI-E 2)
- GPU3: Nvidia GT 9600 (PCI-E/PCH 3)

TL:DR
It seems to me that I somehow need to be able to switch primary GPU from GPU1 to GPU3 in the boot process before drivers are loaded. How can I do that when there is no option to do so in BIOS?

Guides I have been using:
https://mathiashueber.com/windows-virtual-machine-gpu-passthrough-ubuntu/
https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/

---

Edit:

After countless hours and sleepless nights I changed to headless Ubuntu Server 18.04. I changed the third GPU 9600 GT to RTX 2070. I am now able to passthrough all three GPU's to three different VM's at the same time running Windows 10.

I have tried so many different guides and tips to get this to work and unfortunately I cant remember them all. The short version for getting this to work in my case:

- Ubuntu server 18.04 headless without GUI installed.
- Kernel 4.15 or newer
- QEMU 2.11
- If you run UEFI you need to start the Windows 10 VM's with a bios named OVMF_CODE.FD
- If you run UEFI the GPU must support it in the GPU Bios. For Nvidia this is   generally GTX 700 series or newer with a few exceptions.
- The GPU's must be unbound from the default Nouveau driver and bound to VFIO driver before booting the VM's
- When booting the host, one of your GPU's will be set as system primary GPU (even if headless). This is usually the GPU in the first PCI-E slot, but can vary based on the BIOS setting in your mother board. In my case it was the first slot and could not be changed. If you want to passthrough this GPU you first need to reseat the GPU into a different PCI-E slot and use another for primary GPU in the first slot. Then you can dump this GPU's Bios in a file and swap it back as primary GPU in slot 1. This Bios must be provided to the VM that will use the primary GPU.
- Use remote SSH to control the host via terminal when all GPU's are passed through

I am incredibly happy with my setup now. I am able to swap the GPU's between different VM's without rebooting the host via some scripts. There are still some minor issues that I need to fix to get the GPU swapping between VM's to work 100%, but overall the performance is really good.

Comment: Andreas, thank you for sharing your experience. What model of case do you use to fit an RTX 2070 in the bottom PCIe slot?

Comment: I use the old Antec Nine Hundred. It is one of the few midi towers that can fit a dual slot gpu in the bottom PCIe slot. I have been looking for an upgrade, but there are not many good cases that can do this cheap. It is a tight fit, but I have good airflow. I am currently running 2x GTX 970 + RTX 2070 and updated to Ubuntu 20.04.